# .NET Maui iOS not preventing rotation

Tags: ios, maui, info.plist, device-orientation

I've found that on iPad, the app will still rotate even though I have set it not to in the info.plist (see attached). Anyone else have this issue?

[image: info.plist]

Comment: Although you uncheck other orientation in iOS manifest editor, it seems still exists... I think @H.A.H is right. we have to delete it manually.

Comment: Thanks. Also noteworthy that you have to turn on 'Require Full Screen' to turn off the rotation on iPad.

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT the first time I noticed the default editor is hiding content from me, was the last time I used it. How can this go for so long without being fixed is beyond my comprehension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on you plist > Open With > Generic PList Editor.

You will see that there is:

Supported Interface Operations,
And
Supported Interface Operations (iPad)

Start deleting...

Edit: Other editors work as well, even Notepad. Just giving example how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. Also noteworthy that you have to turn on 'Require Full Screen' to turn off the rotation on iPad.